# Картинка из Delphi вставляется в Excel как png, хотя исходная JPEG.Как вставить именно JPEG?

Tags: delphi, excel, jpeg

Есть задача вывода изображения в Excel, вывожу его следующим образом

```
if AImageField.IsNull then
  Exit;
// очередное превью заносим в транзитное хранилище
fmMain.imForEx.EditValue := AImageField.AsVariant;
// вставка картинки
Clipboard.Assign(fmMain.imForEx.Picture);
ESelect(ARow, ACol);
Excel.Selection.PasteSpecial('Рисунок', False, False);
```

Передаю в клипбоард изображение в формате JPEG, но вставляется в Excel png, как можно добиться вставки именно JPEG

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы декодируете jpeg в imForEx и там хранится уже картинка (а не сжатое изображение). И в буфер обмена попадает несжатое изображение. Если очень-очень нужно, то а) убедись, что сам Эксел умеет хранить Jpeg; б) скопируй в буфер обмена и спец утилитой посмотри что внеслось в буфер (формат).

Comment: @VladChapl Excel умеет хранить JPG. Это проверяется вставкой из файла.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Вас ответ удовлетворяет? :)

Comment: @Athari Если честно - нет :) До такого ответа (и даже слегка больше) я докопался и сам. Я не смог разобраться, почему у меня на работе на единственной машине Excel может вставить переданную через клипбоард картинку, как JPG, а на остальных и домашнем компе - нет (везде стоит 2003, плюс местами 2007, 2016). Хорошим ответом была бы, на мой взгляд, обычная вставка картинки с последующей конвертацией в JPEG средствами Excel, если это возможно.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Двойное сжатие с потерями — плохое решение, потому что уничтожает информацию.

Comment: @Athari Да (впрочем, зависит от возможности настраиваемости алгоритмов - можно разжать JPEG и сжать его точно так же, при условии контроля сжатия), но пока я вижу это, как единственно возможный вариант решения ИМЕННО ТАК поставленной задачи. Плюс, не могу понять, почему на одном компе Excel всё-таки имеет варианты вставки в JPG

Comment: @ViktorTomilov "Разжимание" JPEG возможно только при полном доступе к закодированным бинарным данным, так делают некоторые редакторы для редактирования JPEG, чтобы избежать повторного кодирования неизменённых областей. Если же есть только последовательность RGB, то "разжимание" превращается в нетривиальную и очень-очень долгую итеративную операцию без каких-либо гарантий (JPEG имеет очень много параметров кодирования). Выполнять что-то подобное для вставки в Excel — безумие.

Comment: @Athari не спорю, ситуации с Excel'ем это не касалось

Answer (score 3):

Если вы скопируете файл в Проводнике, то в буфере обмена окажется файл как объект оболочки с отсылкой к файловой системе (IDL и ещё какие-нибудь дополнительные форматы). Если вставить в Excel содержимое буфера, то тот прочитает файл и вставит закодированные бинарные данные в формате JPEG как есть.

Если же вы откроете файл в MS Paint и нажмёте Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, то в буфере обмена окажутся голые графические данные в формате BMP, то есть по сути без формата (BITMAP и ещё что-нибудь). Excel, получив такие данные, не сможет ничего сделать, кроме как сохранить последовательность цветов пикселей в удобном ему формате.

Сейчас вы проделываете вторую операцию. Где-то в районе вопроса [Copying files to clipboard and then pasting them into their original folder does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992998/copying-files-to-clipboard-and-then-pasting-them-into-their-original-folder-does) можно найти код для первой операции. Ключевые слова: PIDL, ID List, Shell, Clipboard.

---

Теперь, когда гвоздь забит микроскопом, можно заняться размышлениями о смысле жизни. Зачем вообще этот буфер обмена? В конечном счёте нужно вставить картинку в XLS(X), а мы зачем-то ковыряемся с пользовательским буфером. И юзер будет недоволен, что вы что-то ему затёрли, и у нас ощущение удаления гланд через анус.

XLSX — не самый плохой открытый формат на базе XML. Можно сгенерировать XML документа, засунуть файл JPG в оборачивающий ZIP/XLSX, модифицировать индекс файлов внутри, и всё будет работать, причём вам не потребуется ни запущенный Excel, ни буфер обмена, а только простые файловые операции.

Comment: По поводу "зачем" - я с вами согласен. В 99% случаев это забивание гвоздей даже не микроскопом, а секвенатором :) Но иногда бывает нужно. Хотя решаемо через, например, временный файл.